# How do I include bin/ directory for TFS status/check-in?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS command line from a unix environment.
I need to version control files in the bin/ directory. 
These files are located in the bin/ directory
because they are executable scripts (not compiled).

However, TFS seems to have defaulted to exclude bin/
from analysis. Is there a way to override this on a
project-specific basis ? There are other projects
where bin/ is for depositing compiled programs and
should be excluded. But my project need bin/ directory
to be included.

Is there a counter-file to .tfignore ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

General convention is that "bin" folders should contain only built binaries or copies from other directories.

Your files should be under source control else where, another folder, and only copied to the bin folder at compile time.